# use of powershell for comparing folders

Tags: powershell

I have two folders called "clntfiles" and "clntfilesbkup", I want to compare two folders to check what files in "clntfiles" does not exist in "clntfilesbkup" folder

I am using windows powershell for the purpose

the code I used was

```
$fso = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -path C:\clntfiles

$fsoBU = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -path C:\clntfilesbkup

Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $fso -DifferenceObject $fsoBU
```

this code gives me the exact difference between two folders and the missing files in "clntfilesbkup" folder,

but is there a way powershell can copy all those missing files into another folder and create a text file with names of all those missing files.

Comment: Yes. Yes there is a way that it can do that. I would suggest looking at the Copy-Item and Out-File cmdlets.

Comment: I would suggest using [robocopy to copy the missing files](http://superuser.com/questions/466090/how-to-copy-only-those-files-that-are-not-in-the-destination) and its logging options (`robocopy /?` to see all options available) to write the file listing what was copied (and thus missing originally). Single command, no worrying about a bug in your script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
$fso = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -path C:\clntfiles

$fsoBU = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -path C:\clntfilesbkup

$dif = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $fso -DifferenceObject $fsoBU 

#copy items, sideindicator "<=" indicates object missing in DifferenceObject
$dif | % {if($_.SideIndicator -eq "<="){Copy-Item $_.inputobject.FullName C:\lntfilesbkup}}

#output list to file
$dif.InputObject.FullName | Set-Content dif.txt
```

If you need something else than the full file path in the text file you can check the other available properties with `$dif.InputObject | gm`